# Reading a Java bytecode instruction: What does the number mean?

Tags: java, bytecode

I was reading java bytecode and saw this:

```
getfield #5 (Field java.lang.String name)
```

What does `#5` mean?

And how can I write a program in bytecode?

Comment: By writing a program in Java and compiling it.

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish?  ASM-like optimizations for the JVM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Java class files and bytecode**

Java class files (bytecode-files) is composed by different components:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

- Magic Number: 0xCAFEBABE
- Version of Class File Format: the minor and major versions of the class file
- Constant Pool: Pool of constants for the class
- (...)
- Fields: Any fields in the class
- Methods: Any methods in the class
- Attributes: Any attributes of the class (for example the name of the sourcefile, etc.)

The number #5 simply refers to a location in the constant pool. And in that position a CONSTANT_FieldRef is found which contains a reference to a CONSTANT_NameAndType among other attributes. And CONSTANT_NameAndType contains a reference to a CONSTANT_Utf8 (which contains the actual string/name.)

So the flow looks like this:

```
getfield #number -> FieldRef -> NameAndType -> Utf8 -> string
```

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html

So instead of saving a whole string in each `getfield` instruction a number is saved. This improves performance in the interpreter (or JIT) and space in the class file.

**Hand-write bytecodes**

Hand-written bytecodes can be assembled to a class file with this tool (it contains a lot of examples):

http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

The `getfield` instruction (IIRC) makes a reference into the class file's constant pool for information about what field should be looked up.  The #5 here means "constant pool entry number 5," and this constant pool then contains information saying "look up the field `name` of type `java.lang.String`).  The reason for this is that it keeps the size of the `getfield` instruction the same, regardless of the name or type of the field to look up.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how can I write program in bytecode?"  This is a pretty open-ended question; it's akin to asking how to write programs in any language, and requires a lot of learning.  You may want to look into the [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) Java assembler, which can greatly simplify this process.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

it's constant pool index, constant pool stores all the info of class file, JVM instruction use index to reference class info like fields, methods.

I will use hello world example to show how it works:

**source**:

```
System.out.println("hello world");
```

**bytecode**

```
 0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 3: ldc           #3                  // String hello world
 5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 8: return
```

bytecode instruction is formatted as `instruction  constant pool index`

```
  Constant pool:

   #4 = Methodref          #28.#29        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #28 = Class              #36            // java/io/PrintStream
  #29 = NameAndType        #37:#38        // println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #36 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #37 = Utf8               println
  #38 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

so this instruction will call a method with index 4

`invokevirtual #4`

and index 4 is a `Methodref` of `// java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V`

if we follow the reference in the constant pool, we will find all the information is stored in string and composted to complex type like method, filed, class.

[image]